# How to make a limit for a text? C#

Tags: c#

How can i make a limit to the text box characters?
I mean, when i get to 4 characters the program will not insert more than 4 characters, and if i insert less than 4 characters the program will reset the text, only when i click "confirm".
image:
[image]

the code:

```
namespace ATM_PLUS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox.PasswordChar = '*';
            textBox.ReadOnly = true;

        }

        private void buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            textBox.Text += btn.Text;
        }

        private void ButtonConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox.Text == Globals.PIN)
            {
                Form2 openForm = new Form2();
                openForm.Show();
                Hide();
            }
            if (textBox.Text != Globals.PIN)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password, try again");
                textBox.ResetText();
            }
        }

        private void ButtonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.ResetText();
        }
    }
}
public class Globals
{
    public static Random number = new Random();
    public static int amount = number.Next(1, 9999);
    public static string PIN = "5506";
}
```

Comment: In your Initialize Component where you set the textbox to PaswordChar, you can add textBox.MaxLength = "4"

Comment: FYI - instead of `if (textBox.Text != Globals.PIN)` you could write `else`